# `free` in c doesn't free the memory, why?

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list

I am trying to make LikedList Data structure from scratch.
I made the structure:

```c
typedef struct ListNode {
    int item;
    struct ListNode *back; // point to the Node the before the current Node
    struct ListNode *next; // point to the next node
    struct ListNode *feet; // point to the last Node in the list
} ListNode;
```

The function that pushes the items into the list.

```c
void push_item(ListNode *list, int item) {
    list->feet->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    list->feet->next->back = list->feet;
    list->feet = list->feet->next;
    list->feet->item = item;
}
```

Here and the function which have to pop the last element.

```c
void pop_item(ListNode *list) {
    ListNode *pre = list->feet->back;
    free(list->feet);
    printf("%i\n", list->feet->item); // prints 38 which is the value that I give to the last element with `push_item` function
    pre->next = nullptr;
    list->feet = pre;
}
```

As you can see it prints `32` which is not expected.
I thought that the `free` function will do something such as deleting the allocated element.
Is the problem from my code or what?

Expecting an segment fault or something else

Comment: The `free` function doesn't actually physically remove the memory. It's up to you as the programmer to make sure your programs doesn't access memory that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: Accessing a freed memory is undefined behavior. You're not guaranteed to get a crash, at least not by default. Enabling the address sanitizer should give you an error here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so how i can prevent memory leaks?

Comment: Match every `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and other function allocating memory with a call to `free`. You should just not access that memory once you passed the pointer to `free`.

Comment: @Hasty__ `free` is enough. It tells the allocator that you are done with the memory and that it can be reused.

Comment: @user17732522 well, i didn't knew that. thanks !!

Comment: The point they are making is that free very often doesn't return memory to the OS, but it does return memory to the pool available to malloc. And it also very often doesn't overwrite the memory block, so whatever was in the memory remains there. But an implementation of free is also allowed to return the memory to the OS, in which case you would indeed get a segfault trying to access freed memory.

Comment: You can get the behavior you expected if you use a special implementation of `malloc` that's designed to ferret out "use after free" bugs, such as ASan or Valgrind. But there's a price: your program will run _at least_ 10x slower.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to print an element that you've already freed. This leads to an undefined behavior. Try compiling your code with the `-fsanitize=address` flag and you should see something like  `AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`

Answer (score 2):

`free()` simply returns the memory block to the heap, making it available for reuse.  That is it *frees* it, it does not in any sense *delete* anything.  It does not modify the memory block or the pointer, and it does not remap the memory out of existence.

If you reference that memory via that pointer, *before* it has been reallocated and modified, it's content will in most cases remain unchanged.  That said it is undefined behaviour, so while that is what you might expect, it cannot be relied on, your compiler or debugger, it tools such as Valgrind may instrument malloc/free to detect memory errors.

It is common practice to set the pointer to  null in order to trap attempts to reuse the pointer after it has been free'd:

```
free(list->feet);
list->feet = NULL ;
```

And for security you might even overwrite the memory *before* free in cases where it may contain sensitive data.

Be aware that `free` is not *deletion*.  C++ has a *delete* operator that has additional semantics - it invokes the destructor for the deleted object.

Comment: Slight correction to "its content will in most cases remain unchanged": it's very common for the first two or three machine words of a memory block to get overwritten by some kind of heap bookkeeping data, such as a linked list of all the free blocks, immediately upon passing that block to `free`.

Comment: @zwol.  Perhaps, but "very common" and " in most cases" are not mutually exclusive.  In my experience the heap management data is prependend _before_ the user allocated block, but implementations differ I suppose.